# Python - how to put gtk.DrawingArea scaled fit with gtk.Window width and height?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have this gtk.DrawingArea placed in gtk.Window, but when it runs its not 100% scaled fit with gtk.Widnow height and width.

[image]

Following code is not doing the 100% width/height scale fit to the gtk.Window. Any idea how to get the expected result?

```
  def main(self, screenSaverPicture):    

    self.w = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.w.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(0, 0, 0))

    self.w.set_size_request(1024, 768)

    self.w.set_border_width(0)
    self.w.set_decorated(False)
    self.w.set_title("Screen Saver Screen Locked")        
    self.w.move(0,0)
    #self.w.resize(66,66)

    self.w.set_name("main window")    

    # screenSaverPicture = pictures png or jpeg files shown on the screen 
    self.drawing =  gtk.DrawingArea
    self.drawing.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color('#000000'))   

    self.drawing.connect ('button-press-event',self.callback)
    self.drawing.set_events(gtk.gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK | gtk.gdk.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK | gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK| gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK )

    self.w.add(self.drawing)

    self.w.show_all()
    self.w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    gtk.main()
```

EDIT: Tried but also same

```
self.vbox = gtk.VBox() 
self.vbox.pack_start(self.drawing, expand=True) 
#or self.vbox.pack_start(self.drawing, expand=False) 
self.w.add(self.vbox)
```

or

```
self.vbox = gtk.Fixed()
self.vbox.put(self.drawing, 0,0)
self.drawing.size_request()
self.drawing.size_allocate(gtk.gdk.Rectangle(0,0,1024,768))  
self.w.add(self.vbox)
```

Comment: Could you try `self.w.pack_start(self.drawing)`? I seem to remember that's what I used a while ago.

Comment: @SimonVisser: AttributeError: 'gtk.Window' object has no attribute 'pack_start'

Comment: Not working. Just tried: `self.vbox = gtk.VBox() self.vbox.pack_start(self.drawing, expand=True) self.w.add(self.vbox) `

Comment: First, do you want to resize the window and get DrawingArea resized automatically and keep the ratio at the same time?

Comment: @ilius: YES, but still optional because this window will be not always resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please next time, provide a runnable example, it's boring to have to write the missing parts and comment what is unrelated.

Here's an example that should work. Basically, the code you provide doesn't even have the problem you say you have. The main problem of your initial sample is that you're setting a black background to your `GtkDrawingArea`, instead of a blue one.

```
import gtk

class Test:

    def main(self):
        self.w = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.w.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(0, 0, 0))
        self.drawing =  gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.drawing.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color('#0000ff'))   
        self.w.add(self.drawing)
        self.w.show_all()
        self.w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Test()
    a.main()
```

Comment: First make sure you use `'#0000ff'` as the background color for your drawing area, not `'#000000'`. Then I had to fix the `self.drawing =  gtk.DrawingArea` which is missing the `()` at the end.

Comment: I've modified the example, it's hard to be shorter, unless I remove the fake Test class, but it was to keep your call to the `self` object.

Comment: Please download this: 1) http://paste.ubuntu.com/6555348/ 2) play any avi, flv or anything video file or jpeg or png on it 3) you will notice gtk.Window and gtk.DrawingArea is black and blue but the contents area is not 100% width scaled

Comment: Do you realize that you haven't told us about the fact that vlc is involved ? Chances are libvlc just plays your video by respecting its aspect ratio, which may be different from the one of your monitor. Use a video that has the same aspect ratio as your monitor, or check how to stretch the video using libvlc. But this has nothing to do with GTK at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set static size, and don't draw in `main` or `__init__`

Instead, fetch the size in `expose-event` callback, and draw in that callback depending on the *current* size of widget.

Something like this (your code was incomplete so I couldn't test it)

```
  def main(self, screenSaverPicture):    

    self.w = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    self.w.set_border_width(0)
    self.w.set_decorated(False)
    self.w.set_title("Screen Saver Screen Locked")        
    self.w.move(0,0)
    #self.w.resize(66,66)

    self.w.set_name("main window")    

    # screenSaverPicture = pictures png or jpeg files shown on the screen 
    self.drawing =  gtk.DrawingArea(...) ## FIXME
    self.drawing.connect('expose-event', self.onExposeEvent)

    self.drawing.connect ('button-press-event', self.callback)
    self.drawing.set_events(gtk.gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK | gtk.gdk.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK | gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK| gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK )

    self.w.add(self.drawing)

    self.w.show_all()
    self.w.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
    gtk.main()
  def onExposeEvent(self, widget, event):
    x, y, w, h = widget.allocation
    cr = widget.get_window().cairo_create()
    cr.rectangle(0, 0, w, h)
    cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
    cr.fill()
```

Comment: Its still the same, just did like you have mentioned. but remaining same as it was before.

Comment: Please paste your full code that you are testing (or a part of it that can be executed)